# getting counts for each day in a dataframe

Tags: python

I am currently trying out sentiment analysis on a set of tweets and was wondering how to get counts for the number of tweets in a particular day. The problem for me is that each day is super granular, right down to the second of the tweet being sent. How would I get the counts of tweets for a whole day like the 25th of Jan 2016.[image]

Comment: Could you give a sample of the dataset in a text (i.e. code format), or a snippet of the sample file you're loading from as well as the code you're using to load it?

Comment: You may simply add one more column which contains `day` (trimmed value of `date`) and do `group by ` and `count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, make sure your `date` is actually a `datetime` or similar object. If not, convert it using `pandas.to_datetime()` .

Then extract the date from each datetime:

```
df['date_only'] = df['date'].dt.date
```

And finally groupby:

```
result = df.groupby('date_only').agg({'tweet': 'count'})
```

Comment: @Paul however, in future, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)